# Any danger using performselector in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performselector

I've been stuck for a couple of days with a crash on Crashlytics that says :

**libobjc.A.dylib**

**objc_msgSend**

I managed to point out what seems to be the reason of this crash : **__NSThreadPerformPerform**

With a little search on stack it seems to be linked with **performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:**

The code I have mentions a delay of **0** all the time. I use this method to call out what we could call "functors" in iOS, by recreating selectors dynamically from an array of strings that I access from a enum state.

And basically it's all the informations I have from this so far, I learned that the **afterDelay:** makes your call delayed to the next RunLoop. Does it applies as well on **performSelector:withObject:** or the **afterDelay:** adds something to the method that causes this?

And, finally, the real question :

**Is performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: a good way to make functors, or is it dangerous to use it like this, and should I be doing any other way?**

Thanks in advance,

Comment: As everything in Objective-C, the performSelector is error prone for the developer and can cause a lot of objc_msgSend crashes. This error is mostly caused by calling the selector on the wrong object (the object you're supposed to call is probably deallocated)

Comment: Yes, but I'm aware of this kind of stuff and it's quite the "normal way" to crash when using pointers. But here I can't see how my object could be deallocated at the moment I call it, and even if it waits till the next runLoop how my object could be deallocated if I stay on the same ViewController only using IBOutlet.

Could this be cause by any "memory warning" issue ? ARC should be keeping important ressources for this case shouldn't he?

Comment: Try to enable the Zombie mode for your Debug scheme. Replicate the crash and it should tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Eh, the real problem is that I'm unable to replicate the crash, until now I saw it only on my Crashlytics report, when I tried to replicate it by any way and by doing really bad thing to my app it just never happened.

I'm gonna give a try with zombie enabled, maybe it will crash where I was unable to do it using basic debugger of Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't just assume that your object still exists and can perform selector. Test it before!

```
if ([someObject respondsToSelector:@selector(someSelector)]) {
   [someObject performSelector:@selector(someSelector) withObject:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know how I forgot this haha.

Comment: Well, object not existing (variable being `nil`) is not a problem. Object not being to perform selector would be a problem, but that would indicate that the object is not what the programmer thinks it is.